# How to know the currently running flavor?

Tags: flutter, dart, environment

I want to do something similar to this, but with flutter flavors.

```
const bool.fromEnvironment("dart.vm.product")
```

Comment: What is a main purpose of this? You want to use different configuration in the dart code based on used flavor? Or you just curious how to get flavor name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give every flavor a different packageName you could do it like this:

```
enum EnvironmentType { staging, production }

class Environment {
  EnvironmentType current;

  Environment() {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      switch (packageInfo.packageName) {
        case "com.production.identifier":
          current = EnvironmentType.production;
          break;
        default:
          current = EnvironmentType.staging;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: PackageInfo is not available as an import